# JSON code not parsing also not showing any errors

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm having an issue looping some JSON code, my JSON looks like:

```
{
    "mode_1": [
        "line_1",
        "line_2",
        "etc ..."
    ]
}
```

I have tried with my code:

```
var json = Helpers.GetJsonTemplateToUse(_currentSite, "site_json_1");
dynamic array = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json["mode_1"]);
foreach (var macro in array) 
{
   Helpers.ReturnMessage(macro);
}
```

The `json` var queries and returns the JSON code to parse, then `DeserializeObject` and `foreach` but i think i have done it wrong, I don't get any erros as such but the `ReturnMessage` function does not output any lines, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try the following :  `string[] modes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[]>(json["mode_1"]);`

Comment: it seems you just need to do `foreach (string macro in json["mode_1"])` for it to work.

Comment: What is returned by `Helpers.GetJsonTemplateToUse`?

Comment: ```Helpers.GetJsonTemplateToUse``` just returns the JSON code like above.

Comment: What is returned by `json["mode_1"]`, then? It looks like you're parsing half your JSON in one spot and another half in another spot.

Answer (score 1):

You probably do not get any error message because you are using `dynamic`

Try:

```
var array = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourModel>(json["mode_1"]);
```

`YourModel` should be your custom Json object class